# How can I import assets of type folder shared by my co-worker?

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, geometry, editing, import

I am very new to Google Earth Engine. My coworker shared his asset folder with me but as i open the link it gives me an error that "Unable to import asset of type folder".

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please edit your question with the precise steps you took to share/import your data? Also are the geometry and editing tags pertinent to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide an example of where this appears I'm not sure exactly how you got to this problem (please edit your question with more detail if you would like more explanation), but what the error message *means* is: The "import" action, for *using an asset in a script*, does not apply to folders, which just organize assets.

It is not necessary, either: you only need to import the image, image collection, or table asset that you want to use in the script (whether it is in a folder or not).